# Can I limit to getting only the latest change of a Site Colletion in CSOM

Tags: csom, changelog, getchanges

I am using the following to get changes that happened in a Site Collection.

```
ChangeToken token = new ChangeToken();
token.StringValue = lastChangeToken;

ChangeQuery query = new ChangeQuery(true, true);
query.ChangeTokenStart = token;

ChangeCollection changecol = site.GetChanges(query);
context.Load(changecol);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

This returns all the changes since the last change token.

I want only the very latest change to get the Site Collection's updated last change token. So, I am looking for something that returns only the last change rather than getting all changes as there might be a considerable time difference.

I tried `query.FetchLimit = 1; query.LatestFirst = true;` but got error as "Specified method is not supported." while ExecuteQuery. I even tried to use `ChangeLogItemQuery` but `site.GetChanges` does not accept it.

Comment: CSOM only? perhaps powershell: `$listTitle = "Test"
$list = $context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listTitle)
$qry = new-object Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.ChangeQuery($true,$true)
$changes = $list.GetChanges($qry)
$context.Load($changes)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
$changes | select ChangeType, Time`

Comment: This is the powershell version of CSOM. However this still requests all changes from the sharepoint made to the list. (`$context.Load($changes)`) . But, I want to form a query that requests only the latest change to sharepoint itself.

Answer (score 1):

> The following code snippet will get all the changes to a site collection:

```
ChangeQuery siteCQ = new ChangeQuery(true, true);  
var siteChanges = site.GetChanges(siteCQ);  
clientContext.Load(siteChanges);  
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (Change change in siteChanges)  
{
 Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", change.ChangeType, change.TypedObject);
}
```

[Source](https://www.schaeflein.net/reading-the-sharepoint-change-log-from-csom/)

Comment: Please.. This is what I do currently. But I want to get only the latest change without requesting all changes to server.